# When to add Solr jar files to web app instead of using Solrj?

Tags: solr

I am investigating how to incorporate Solr in an existing web application.

I have found two basic paths to incorporate Solr into an existing web application.  One is to [unpack solr.war, add the Solr jar files to the WEB-INF/lib of my app and use the org.apache.solr classes directly in my application](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.ch/2011/07/adding-solr-to-existing-web-application.html).  In other words, no separate Solr server instance.

The other is to use Solrj to query data from a separate Solr server instance.

My first impression is that the Solrj approach is the more robust one (not having actually used it yet).

So, my question is:  Under what circumstances would I use the first approach (unpack solr.war and add the jar files to my own app)?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

Comment: @MauricioScheffer If I read that correctly Solrj can be used in two ways:  to connect to a remote Solr server using HTTP and to embed Solr into my application (no remote server needed).  Further, embedding is generally not recommended.  But if one does choose to embed, they should use Solrj for it and the link in my post is no longer the way to embed Solr.

Comment: Yes, the code is quite similar to the post but the wiki is always the authoritative source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of Solr as an analogy of a relational database server: reasons to use an embedded database are reasons to use solr that way. Choosing separate Solr server has these pros:

- better manageability (able to update, restart, configure independently)
- available for multiple clients

Some cons:

- communication overhead
- more complicated deployment

My default choice would be separate instance, the overhead is not big.

Comment: indeed. Use a separate server unless you have very good reasons not to. (a testing environment would be one for example). Both embedded and remote can be talked to through solrJ. In fact, after the initial 2/3 lines of setup code the rest of your code doesn't even know/care if it's talking to a remote or embedded server.